# Can’t boot in to Windows or reinstall Windows when I turn FTPM on in BIOS

Tags: windows, boot, bios

I’ve been trying to update my Windows 10 to 11 and I know you need secure boot UEFI mode enabled and TPM2.0

I have enabled all of those things in BIOS and for some reason when I try to boot in to Windows which is already installed in UEFI mode, windows goes straight to recovery mode. If  I try to reinstall Windows through a USB it just shows a blue screen after the splash screen and after about 5/10 seconds it completely shuts off.

Comment: Run PC Health Check App (Microsoft) or WhyNotWin11 (GitHub) and check your PC for true Windows 11 compatibility.

Comment: What is your computer model, and was TPM the only tweak you did in the BIOS? Is your disk GPT?  Is the BIOS set to Legacy or Secure Boot is off, and is the SATA Operation mode AHCI or IDE or RAID?

Comment: I have a custom built pc, the TPM was the only thing I changed in bios, my hard drives are in GPT, the pc is set to secure boot on and the operation mode is AHCI